# MS Access Update Unbound Form with Bound Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have three forms in a database. Forms A, B, C. The parent form is A and the child form is B at a one to many relationship. As I put information into Form B I would like to click a button on different records and have Form C which is also located on Form A population with the correct information.

I created a query that controls Form C which reads with the following

```
[Forms]![frm_A1_SiteInformation]![frm_A1A_OutletInformation].[Form]![outletID]
```

This is to update the query with the new pass through key when I perform the docmd.Requery command.

This is where I get confused because I cannot get Form C to refresh with the correct information. It just keeps saying the first record.

Comment: Odd title. If form is UNBOUND it would not have a RecordSource. Edit question to post code that has the Requery method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoCmd.Requery` just requeries whatever object has focus. Could do:

```
Forms!FormA.FormCsubformcontainerName.SetFocus
DoCmd.Requery
```

Or just:

`Forms!FormA.FormCsubformcontainerName.Requery`

Or if you want to requery and put focus on FormC:

`Forms!FormA.FormCsubformcontainerName.Form.Requery`

Comment: I think the `.Form` is needed after the sub-form control name to requery.

Comment: Nope. Works either way. Including `.Form` will put focus on first record of that form.

Comment: @June7 It worked perfectly. I totally forgot about the Get Focus command. I got so focused on the application that I missed what my tools where. Thank you so much for bringing me back.